# how can force user to logout after 30 minutes(for example) in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, pyrocms

is there way that if user have any activity in 30 minutes, that user logout automatically.
I use **Ion_auth** authentication in Codeigniter.

Comment: Use Javascript and make a redirect after 30min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the file `system/cms/config.php` and set the option `$config['sess_expiration']` to the value you'd like to have (in seconds, so 30 minutes would be 1800 seconds).

Keep in mind that this won't immediately throw your user out of the session, but he will have to relog the next time he'll request something that utilises the session (e. g. a password protected page).

Answer (score 2):

Before you start a session, you could set the lifetime of the session cookie, defined in seconds.

For example:

```
session_set_cookie_params(43200,"/");
session_start();
```

12 Hours = 12 * 60 Minutes = 12 * 60 * 60 Seconds => 43200 seconds
Now your session should expire in 12Hours

For your example: 30 Minutes * 60 Seconds => 1800 seconds

For information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript redirect to logout page after 30 minutes:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){       
    window.location.href = "/logout";
}, 1800000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using sessions? You could set a session variable up to expire after 30 minutes, the system will check for inactivity. Once the session times out, it will automatically log the user out.